# How to simulate user request from different location over the world?

Tags: cloud, distributed-computing, bigdata

Currently, I have a project which requires me to simulate users request from different geographical locations over the world for testing purpose. For example, my server is located in Australia and I need to simulate users' request from Beijing, US, and EU.

I know about Planetlab which allows researchers to get access to server resources in different geographical locations but it requires your organisation to take part in its consortium.

Is anyone know some kinds of tool or system that can help me? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the appropriate country proxy and simulate the requests as if they are coming from that geography.

you can use the free proxies available http://proxy-list.org/english/index.php and then configure your browser to use any of these proxies and then start browsing / sending requests to your site.

You can also do that programatically. For example if you are using C# you can use this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172495.aspx

There are some tools like geopeeker https://www.geopeeker.com which provide similar services. you need to check their API feature list to see if that would help your requirement.